# Single table version controled data

Tags: ruby, postgresql, relational-database

So I have a table designed as such:

```
create_table "entries", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "id", :null => false, :autoincrement => true
  t.text     "text"
  t.string   "uuid"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
end
```

I have a similar problem to " [Database - data versioning in single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205295/database-data-versioning-in-single-table)" except that I have multiple sources (some of which do work offline) writing into this database, so the `current` bit doesn't really work well for me.

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to get the most recent of each UUID.

In sqlite: `SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" GROUP BY uuid ORDER BY updated_at DESC` works great, but it's not valid syntax in postgres, and it kind of feels janky. Is there a good way to do this, or do I need to redo my schema?

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the results you're after is to use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) and a derived table. ActiveRecord doesn't understand either of those but there's always `find_by_sql`:

```
Entry.find_by_sql(%q{
    select id, text, uuid, created_at
    from (
        select id, text, uuid, created_at,
               row_number() over (partition by uuid order by created_at desc) as r
        from entries
    ) as dt
    where r = 1
})
```

The interesting part is this:

```
row_number() over (partition by uuid order by created_at desc)
```

`partition by uuid` is similar to `group by uuid` but it doesn't collapse the rows, it just modifies how the `row_number()` window function behaves so that `row_number()` is computed with respect to rows with matching `uuid`s; the `order by created_at desc` similarly applies only to the window that `row_number()` will be looking at. The result is that `r = 1` peels off the first row in each group.